# How do I remove Mobile Broadband connections that don't appear under "Edit Connections..."?

Tags: network-manager, bluetooth, mobile-broadband

When I first tried to use my mobile to connect to the internet, I created a Mobile Broadband connection. I did this by opening Bluetooth > Preferences and ticking "Access the Internet using your mobile phone (DUN)". Usually, when my phone is within Bluetooth range I open the Network indicator, click on the mobile connection, and it is established.

Sometimes, however, this doesn't work and the Bluetooth connection times out. [1] Then, the only way I can establish an internet connection is to again open Bluetooth > Preferences and tick the box again. This creates a brand new Mobile Broadband connection. When I click on the new mobile connection, it works.

However, I now have several duplicate mobile connections under my Network indicator. When I click on "Edit Connections...", they do not appear under the Mobile Broadband tab. Nor when I run `gksu nm-connection-editor`.

Where are they stored and how do I get rid of them?

[1] I assume this is a bug. Advice what to do when it happens again so I can file it accurately would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NM connections are stored in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`

I assume the bug is https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-bluetooth/+bug/822311

Comment: On 10.04, /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ is empty & nm-applet is still showing bluetooth-dun connection.Any idea where these settings are stored on gnome2?

Comment: IIRC it was somewhere in `~/.gconf`. Try searching in `gconf-editor` for a corresponding name...

Comment: Thanks. I found it under ~/.gconf/system/networking/connections/10! I have to delete the entire folder to get rid of it from network-manager.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that this still happens on 12.04 LTS

Thank you for the solution :) int_ua. 
Deleting the corresponding files in that location removed the duplicates.

Additionally, D3vid, if you want to avoid creating a duplicate, you can do the following:

Click on the Network Indicator, and uncheck Enable Networking.

This disables networks. Next repeat the same, thus enabling networks.

Previously used network connections are now visible. You can use them instead of going to the bluetooth applet and creating a new connection.

I find this takes lesser time than the bluetooth applet.

Comment: On 12.04.2 I found the connections in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections.

Comment: I deleted them from /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections, but they come back after a while and when I restart NetworkManager.