# How do I delete the list of Bluetooth DUN connections?

Tags: network-manager, bluetooth

I have ended up with a [huge list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1nGq.png) of DUN connections, which are duplicates of a single device.

Any idea how I should delete them? I looked around in `/etc/bluetooth` and a few directories in my home directory.

Comment: On gnome2 it was under ~/.gconf/system/networking/connections/.Deleting the required folder would delete the connection from nm-applet.On Gnome3 it is supposed to be under /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/, but doesn't work due to a bug.see the answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124861/how-do-i-remove-mobile-broadband-connections-that-dont-appear-under-edit-connection)

Comment: I found those connections in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` and deleted them. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for this. It was becoming annoying to see all the duplicate bluetooth DUNs listed. Found all of them in the /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections folder and deleted the duplicates. Thanks.

Comment: @KhurshidAlam  Can you include a answer with instructions on how to do that? [Leaving a half-answer as a comment](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments) can often cause more harm than good. Thanks.

Comment: I added an answer. Hope thats OK.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All the DUN connections can be found in the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` Choose your pick, or delete all of them.

The command to delete the connection is

`sudo rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/name-of-connection`

Alternatively, you can delete all using the following command:

`sudo rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*`

Just a word of advice, it will delete any wi-fi or ethernet connections too.

If this does not delete the entries, try disabling and then enabling networking by clicking on "Enable Networking".

Comment: great answer, although this seems like a bug or incomplete feature in Ubuntu